# why does cin works wheras cin.getline doesn't?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

My code is

```
char buffer[10]={0};
cin>>buffer; //here i enter the contents as "12345678912345"
//Now i tried to enter 14 characters into a buffer of 10
cin>>buffer; //This works as it waits for input on the console
cout<<buffer;
```

wheras

```
char buffer[10]={0};
cin>>buffer;//same input as above "12345678912345"
cin.getline(buffer,10);//This doesn't wait for input on console and returns 
cout<<buffer;
```

why does this happen?

THANKS:
     thanks everyone for your answers they were helpful

Comment: Are you asking why you get undefined behaviour after a buffer overrun? That's because buffer overruns cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: but in case of cin>> it works fine

Comment: No it doesn't; it writes past the end of the buffer, corrupting memory and causing undefined behaviour. It might appear to work for you, if there happens to be nothing important in the corrupted memory; but in principle anything could happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your code-snippets "work" in the sense that both overflow the buffer in the first input line. This is not a good thing at all.

The second case doesn't wait for input because of technical differences between `operator>>` and `getline` - they react differently to the newline character that you have entered. When reading the first `cin >> buffer`, the newline at the end of the input is left in the input stream (`cin`). In your first case, the second `cin >> buffer` will skip over the newline that is in the input buffer, and then wait for more input.

In the second case, because of the workings of `getline`, it accepts the remaining newline as input, and buffer is not filled in with anything.

This is a common problem when mixing `getline` and `operator>>` for input. The best solution to solve that particular problem is to either use only `operator >>` or only `getline` - there are various other solutions, but they are generally quite tricky to get just right.

Comment: so does it mean this wil happen only once after a buffer overrrun for cin.getline, the next time will getline wait for input?

Comment: Assuming you DON'T overflow the buffer, the next getline should work. Since you are overflowing the buffer, who knows what gets overwritten and what happens - it's called undefined behaviour, and it really does mean "something strange may happen". Have you checked that your `cin` stream isn't in an error condition, for example?

Comment: Something like `if (cin) cout << "Error on cin\n";` would do that.

Answer (score 3):

First off you have a buffer overrun: Reading to a `char*` stops when the stream goes bad, a space is found, or the `width()` is exhausted if it were bigger than 0. You want to use

```
std::cin >> std::setw(10) >> buffer;
```

Assuming this undefined behavior is abouded, the difference between using formatted and unformatted input for the second read is that formatted input starts with skipping leading whitespace whike unformatted input does not. Your first input stopped right before the newline character resulting from the enter key. That newline is good enough for `getline()` but it is skipped when using `>>`.

When switching between formatted and unformatted I/O you normally want to skip leading whitespace using, e.g., the `std::ws` manipulator:

```
(std::cin >> std::ws). getline(buffer, 10);
```

You should also consider using `std::string` together with `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you input the value for buffer in console, the return is still stored in the input stream.

Hence the termination character `'\n'` is already read by `getline()` from the previous read operation. This is why this function does not wait further for user input.

Try reading the `getline()` before the `cin >>` operation.

Also, as noted by Mike, you should be careful not to cause buffer overflow.

Comment: but even if i add awhile loop after that...it keeps on executing everytime and never waits for input..

Comment: Did you try to make the change I suggested?

Comment: i want to know the reason for this behaviour...so i am using this sequence

Comment: @singh see this. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline From the link it is clear that getline terminates on EOL character. This EOL character is read by getline() before your second input because you press enter while entering your first input. This 'enter' is not read by cin but stays in the input buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator does not consume any whitespace including the newline. The `getline` function returns when it sees a newline. Your problem is the newline that `>>` statement leaves at the buffer. You can solve this by consuming all characters, including the newline until you see a newline in the buffer. See the [ignore function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/):

```
char buffer[10]={0};
cin>>buffer;
cin.ignore('\n', 256);
cin.getline(buffer,9); 
cout<<buffer;
return 0;
```